# ¿Por qué me aparecen valores nan si ya los he quitado?

Tags: python, csv

Mi archivo csv tenia valores NaN y los he tratado rellenándolos. Sin embargo, al ejecutar el código que os muestro, me aparece que tengo valores nan.

```
from numpy import set_printoptions
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif

test = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=3)
fit = test.fit(X,y)
set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(fit.scores_)
features = fit.transform(X)
print(features[0:5,:])
```

salida:

```
[2.689e+00 4.682e-03 4.510e-02 1.387e+00 7.068e-01 9.605e-01 1.499e+00
 2.779e-01 5.321e+00 3.014e+00 6.066e-01 1.130e+01 9.206e+00 7.016e+00
       nan 2.747e-01 2.747e-01 1.258e+00 6.842e-02 1.484e+01 6.842e-02
       nan 1.419e+01 6.842e-02 1.370e-01 8.207e+00 6.356e-01 4.782e-01
 2.275e+01 1.111e+01 2.275e+01 2.180e+01]
[[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [True True False]
 [False False False]]
```

Comment: Mira bien el csv, que hayas metido esos valores adicionales como números válidos. Si no, te podrán aparecer de nuevo como nan. Por ejemplo, que hayas usado punto en vez de coma (o viceversa) como comparador de decimales.

Comment: Entinedo, el csv tenia valores "?" pero yo los trate de la siguiente manera:
import pandas as pd.data = r.csv', na_values=['?'])
data.head()
y posteriormente hice:
data = data.fillna(data.mean())
luego hice un: 
data.isnull().values.any()
para verificar que no existe valores desconocidos y me sigue saliendo ¿Sabrias alguna solución que me pueda ayudar?
Un saludo.